# redirect to a dynamically non existing address using php

Tags: php, apache

I have a userprofile system in which a dynamic page (profile.php) changes as the id of user changes..
For eg. profile.php?id=2 displays the profile of user having id=2.. But i want the address to be as user/user_name.php. So providing each user a unique profile-page address..
Is it possible without creating a seperate page for each user?
Thnx

Comment: Just commenting after reading your title.. How can you redirect a user to non existing address?

Comment: look in to apache mod rewrite

Comment: Thnx , apache mod rewrite lookd at it but i'm not getting anything.
It would be helpful if you could provide me its exact code

Comment: You don't have username in the url - so it's two steps 1) rewrite `user/username.php` (why the .php?) to `something.php` and in that file lookup the user by id and process it.

Comment: Old question, but why would you want to do this? You're opening a massive security hole by putting the username in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let´s talk about apache´s mod_rewrite. Basically what people usually do is that they setup one php page eg. index.php and redirect all the requests there (except those that request existent files and directories) and index.php then routes these requests to proper files/presenters/controllers, etc.

I´m gonna show you a very simple example how can this be done, it´s just to give you the idea how it works in basics and ofc there are better ways to do this (for example take a look at some framework).

So here is the very simple .htaccess file, placed in the same directory as index.php:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # prevents files starting with dot to be viewed by browser
    RewriteRule /\.|^\. - [F]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php?query=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And here is the index.php:

```
<?php
    $request = explode("/", $_GET["query"]);
    // now you have your request in an array and you can do something with it
    // like include proper files, passing it to your application class, whatever.
    // for the sake of simplicity let me just show you the example of including a file
    // based on the first query item

    // first check it´s some file we want to be included
    $pages = array("page1", "page2", "page3");
    if(!in_array($request[0], $pages)) $request[0] = $pages[0];
    include "pages/".$request[0];
```

But I highly recommend you not to reinvent the wheel and take a look at some existing php framework. You´ll find out that it saves you a lot of work, once you learn how to use it ofc. To mention some - [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/), [Symfony](http://symfony.com/) and the one I´m using - [Nette Framework](http://nette.org/en/). There are many more, so choose whatever suits your needs.

Comment: You've taken a simple mod-rewrite+php-logic question and turned into "how to write your own front controller" - you don't answer the question.